# Trying to understand MVC. Is this right?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, events, design-patterns, chess

The way it was explained was through the use of events and the publish/subscribe model. Basically, the model would just be the data and it would have no knowledge of the view/GUI/UI. The model is typically just an abstract object that operates on its data and can perform operations and whatnot.

The view is a different class that responds to changes in the model and usually displays this data to the user. Previously, I did not know how this could occur without coupling between the view and model but having it explained with events clears that confusion up a lot. Does this mean that the model contains public events that itself raises when something interesting happens? For example, if we were programming a game of Chess, when a piece was moved, the model would raise the event of `PieceMoved` with the necessary information (which piece, moved from where to where, etc.) and the view could subscribe to such an event and then show an animation of the piece moving from its old square to its new square.

The part that still confuses me is the exact nature of the controller. I'm having trouble understanding how it supplies the model and view with new information. I imagine the controller contains references to the model and view. Keeping with the Chess example, would the controller just respond to user input (for example to move a piece) and then just suggest to the model what piece wants to move to where? Then the model takes this information, sees if it's a legitimate move, and if so, update the model accordingly, raise the `PieceMoved` event, to which the view reacts and updates the graphical realm accordingly?

Lastly, how does the controller find out which piece is trying to be moved? It seems like that type of thing is heavily tied to the view (let's say moving involved first clicking the piece you wish to move and then the destination square). I imagine the controller would respond to a mouse click and sends those coordinates to the model but how would the model know how to translate those coordinates to find which piece was selected? Isn't that heavily tied to the view? It seems like the view would have to perform some logic processing instead of simply responding to the model and controller but then it wouldn't be a proper view anymore (instead a view/model mix).

Comment: Long question and a full answer would be even longer. Read a few books first. Not completely off-topic but way too broad.

Comment: I'll try and make the question more specific and shorter. Okay, hopefully that is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad things about the MVC pattern are:

- Everyone has her/his own version
- It is a bit abstract to be grasped at first

The good things:

- It is actually pretty simple
- It is a fantastic way of dividing up most applications

To answer your question though:

**The model**

This is a easy one. The model should know only about itself. It is the *board*, the *pieces* and the rules of the game. You know you are building your model right if you could reuse it either in a desktop application or a web one.

**The view**

This isn't complex either. It is the visual part, and the one that deals with the user input. The most important concept to understand the role of views in the MVC pattern is that they must provide a way to make calls to the puclic interface of your system. In the chess game, it is the one that has to draw the elements and detect what the user is doing with the mouse/keyboard. When the user does something it is the view the responsible of calling the system: eg. "User1 wants to move piece from X to Y" (Important: most of the time you don't want the view to trigger a call like User1 clicked in coordinates x, y. Pixels are the realm of the view. The system has to receive orders that are independent of how they are graphically represented).

**The controller**

You're right, this one isn't that straightfoward. The controller is the one that has to process calls to the public interface to the system. In your example it will receive a call 'User1 moves from X to Y' and call a method in the appropiate object of the model (very likely the *board* in this case). Thus, the controller *totally* knows about the objects in the model. However it can also contain the code that is necessary in the application but that doesn't belong to the domain of your model. You have to check if the user has permission to access the system? You have to log that call into a file? Well, most of the time that kind of things go into the controller.

However, that's just my own version of MVC (I, like everyone else, also have my own too... :)

Answer (score 0):

MVC is a pretty generic concept.  There are tons of different ways that it has been implemented, and most of them have compromises of one sort or another.

The problem I see is that you are trying to take an esoteric concept and apply concrete implementation details to it.  That's hard to do unless you have a very specific implementation in mind (asp.net MVC, fubuMVC, spring MVC, smalltalk MVC, whatever) and each one accomplishes things like notifications and event handling in a different manner.

If you're just talking about the MVC concept, then you have to deal with the MVC concepts in a generic way.  I know it may be easier to understand if you have a concrete implementation, but then you go down the path of understanding the pattern (MVC) based on the understanding of the implementation, which can skew your understanding of the pattern itself.

So when you read about messages or events, you have to just think "some mechanism that is implementation defined".  It could be a callback, or it could be a C# event, or it could be a Windows message, or it could be using the force ;)

EDIT:

Regarding your update, I will repeat.  You can't answer implementation specific details about a generic concept.  You would have to define a specific implementation for someone to be able to tell you how those implementation details are accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of answers to this question, mainly because there are so many different MVC frameworks. Have a look at http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html for some examples. I can also give an MVVM perspective mainly since this is what I've been working on these days so this is how I'm thinking.

The Model layer is basically your data and your business logic. You might be talking to a database or a webservice here. If you end up writing a system, that is more than a just a GUI, this is your reusable code.

The ViewModel then sits on top the Model, and basically presents (ahem) the data as properties. It uses an INotifyPropertyChanged interface to tell the UI when data changes. If you have data that you are using to build something up before pushing it to the model layer, it lives here. You will normally expose the actions that you can perform in the UI as ICommnands.

The View layer is the least coupled, because it just uses binding to connect to the ViewModel. Things to visualise are properties that are bound with optional IValueConverters used to change its form, e.g.

```
Visibilty="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibiltyConverter}}"
```

Action UI elements are bound to the Commands on the ViewModel to kick off the ViewModel actions.

```
Command="{Binding DoSomething}"
```

Answer (score -1):

So if you have a view (the chess board) and a controller for the chess board, the controller would house the events for it. When you move a piece it raises the `PieceMoved` event which should pass information to this event such as current position, and desired position.

For a very simple application you may not grasp the concept of models. One might have a billing model that could be reused on multiple views (such as a detail and create view). You wouldn't want to duplicate this code every time you needed it, so in your controller each event would reach out to the billing model that needed it. By creating a model you are encapsulating your code.